# Does changing charset effect joins performance

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I am multiple databases on 1 server. I do cross database joins. Tables are of different charsets. I read that if i join such tables it will be problem for performance. So if i make all DB/tables as 1 charset will it help performance? Will it cause any problem for other normal queries? Which is better UTF8 or latin?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a join comparing text columns of different character sets cannot use an index, so it ends up doing a table-scan on the second table in the join, *for every row* of the first table. This kills performance.

I recommend just going with utf8 from the start, if it's text. Because if someone submits utf8 characters to your app and then the app stores them in a latin1 field, it's a mess to clean up.

Comment: Will it effect any existing queries? i mean to say break any queries?

Comment: I can't answer that for your application. You'll have to test carefully.